# How would I get the red key in the room full of traps in Qasir Al-Wasat?

Tags: qasir-al-wasat

In [*Qasir Al-Wasat: A Night in-Between*](http://qasir.adugestudio.com/), I'm stuck in the room full of traps. I'm trying to get that red key, not [à la *Indiana Jones And The Raiders Of The Lost Ark*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlZCv.png) since the traps are on the floor all around the pedestal.

[image: Qasir Al-Wasat: A Night in-Between]

I've looked throughout all locations and found nothing which could help, so I believe this is a puzzle based on logic, timing or skill. If this is not the case, could you point me to the rooms where I could further investigate?

---

When the hero dies, the screen gets brighter, and I still cannot see any missing pressure plate.

[image: No visible missing pressure plate]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closely (its easier with more brightness) there's a this pressure plate missing in the back.

Here, I made a video showing how to get the Key...